# how to delete rows of specific id after true value on r

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
id    true/false
 1      false
 1      false  
 1      false    
 1      true
 1      false    
 1      false    
 1      false
 2      false  
 2     false    
 2      true
 2      false    
 2      false
```

I want to delete all the rows for specific id after true value on r.
The result will be:

```
 id   true/false
 1      false
 1      false  
 1      false    
 1      true
 2      false  
 2      false    
 2      true
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column name be `true_false` instead of true/false, you can use `dplyr` as

```
library(dplyr) 

df  %>%  group_by(id)  %>% filter(cumsum(+(lag(true_false) == "true")) <1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using a `datastep()`:

```
library(libr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# Sample data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
id       TF
 1      false
 1      false  
 1      false    
 1      true
 1      false    
 1      false    
 1      false
 2      false  
 2     false    
 2      true
 2      false    
 2      false')


df2 <- df %>% 
  datastep(by = "id", 
           retain = list(del = FALSE),
                {
  if (first.)
    del <- FALSE
                  
  if (TF == "true")
    del <- TRUE
  
  }) %>% 
  filter(del == FALSE | TF == 'true') %>% 
  transmute(id, TF)

df2
# id    TF
# 1  1 false
# 2  1 false
# 3  1 false
# 4  1  true
# 5  2 false
# 6  2 false
# 7  2  true
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(lag(cumsum(as.logical(true_false)), default = 0) == 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id true_false
#  <int> <chr>     
#1     1 false     
#2     1 false     
#3     1 false     
#4     1 true      
#5     2 false     
#6     2 false     
#7     2 true
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), true_false = c("false", "false", "false", "true", "false", 
"false", "false", "false", "false", "true", "false", "false")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```